# Вывод результата сравнения строк

Tags: javascript

Есть 2 строки, хочу вывести разницу между ними после их сравнения. Для этого я решила преобразовать их к массивам, потом сравнивать эти массивы, полученный массив обратно в строку и на вывод, но это решение громоздкое, может существует какое-то более легкое и изящное решение?

Код: https://codepen.io/yiulia-okushko/pen/wQGBrK?editors=1010
**Важно**:буду благодарна любым подсказкам, но прошу ориентироваться только на чистый JS

Код *.js:

```
var beforeChange=document.getElementById('mainBlock').innerHTML;

function conversion(){ 

    var afterChange=document.getElementById('mainBlock').innerHTML;

    var beforeChangeArray =beforeChange.split('');
    var afterChangeArray =afterChange.split('');    

    function arr_diff (a1, a2) { 
        var a = [], diff = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < a1.length; i++) {
            a[a1[i]] = true;
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < a2.length; i++) {
            if (a[a2[i]]) {
                delete a[a2[i]];
            } else {
                a[a2[i]] = true;
            }
        }
        for (var k in a) {
            diff.push(k);
        }
        return diff;
    }
    var difference = arr_diff(beforeChangeArray,afterChangeArray);
     console.log("Difference = "+ difference)

}
```

Comment: Приведите пример вашего решения, возможно есть способы его упростить.

Comment: Для начала скажите что именно вы понимаете под _разницей между строками_

Comment: @hindmost str1="abcd"; str2="abFFFcd", под разницей я понимаю "FFF"

Comment: А если `str1="abcde"; str2="abFFFcd"`?

Comment: @hindmost, первая строка неизменна, в нее вношу правки и получаю вторую строку, мне нужно достать эти изменения, я правила вопрос и прикрепила код

Comment: @Let'ssayPie, правила вопрос, добавила код

Comment: Переноси код в вопрос